# Tensorflow requires numpy version ~=1.19.2, matplotlib requires numpy version 1.23.0

Tags: python, numpy, dependency-management

I'd expect it to be a fairly common problem when installing a lot of python packages that there would be dependency collisions like package A depending on a certain version of package C and package B depending on another version of package C as a result of which both A and B cannot coexist in a project.

In my case this happens with tensorflow requiring numpy 1.19.2 and matplotlib requiring numpy 1.23.0.

Are there known workarounds to this or do you just have to pick one of them?

Comment: Can you not just install an older version of matplotlib? conda install matplotlib=3.6 as per https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/min_dep_policy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can try installing an older matplotlib version, which will likely be compatible with the python version required by tensorflow.

That said, I recommend that you use Python's [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) (if you're not already using it). You will be able to install/test different libraries versions without messing up the ones on your system.